# How to add custom information in see details of mini cart in magento2 frontend

Tags: magento2

When we click on see details then details will shown.
whatever customer would provided in the form.
I want like this image

[image]

Comment: please explain more

Comment: When click on see details tabs then the subscription details will be shown in frontend

Comment: Please help me to do this